# how to search in multiple table?

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables medicalhistory and patient in medicalhistory i have fields name DoctorId and PatientId and in patient ihave PatientId, FirstName,MiddleName,LastName

as of now my query is this it only filter one table and the patientid from medicalhistory.

```
$dids = $_SESSION["DoctorId"];
if(isset($_POST["btnsrch"])&& ($_POST["textbox"]!="")){
   $pid = $_POST["textbox"];
    $pid= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["textbox"]);

   $query2= mysqli_query($link,"Select DISTINCT PatientId from medicalhistory where DoctorId='". $dids ."' or PatientId='". $pid ."'" );

}
```

my problem is how will i query the FirstName MiddleName and LastName but it will query only the name that have records on that doctor in medicalhistory ?

Comment: Read about MySQL joins its a simple enough problem you have and there is hundreds of questions/articles on this

Comment: icant find the same problem as mine

Comment: Join your tables and then use whichever column from whichever table as your where clause. Your problem is 101. currently you have NO join. Create join, try it and post results

Comment: $query2= mysqli_query($link,"SELECT p.PatientId FROM patient p INNER JOIN medicalhistory as pa ON (p.PatientId = pa.PatientId) WHERE pa.PatientId='".$pid."'" );

Comment: You probably need an `AND`. Post code in your question its not readable in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query2= mysqli_query($link,"SELECT p.PatientId,p.firstname,p.middlename,p.lastname 
FROM patient p 
INNER JOIN medicalhistory as pa ON (p.PatientId = pa.PatientId) 
WHERE pa.PatientId='".$pid."'" );
```

**This would be your code which is modified:**

```
$dids = $_SESSION["DoctorId"];
if(isset($_POST["btnsrch"])&& ($_POST["textbox"]!="")){
    $pid = $_POST["textbox"];
    $pid= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["textbox"]);

    $query2= mysqli_query($link,"SELECT p.PatientId, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName,pa.doctorID,pa.Evaluation FROM patient p INNER JOIN medicalhistory as pa ON (p.PatientId=pa.PatientId) WHERE pa.PatientId='".$pid."'" );
}
```

Sample Output:

```
mysql> select p.id,p.First,p.last, p.middle,pa.id,pa.evalution from test1 as p left join test as pa on (p.id=pa.id) where p.first='Dan' and p.id=4 and p.last='smi
th';
+----+-------+-------+----------+----+-----------+
| id | First | last  | middle   | id | evalution |
+----+-------+-------+----------+----+-----------+
|  4 | Dan   | Smith | chandran |  4 | sick      |
+----+-------+-------+----------+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: doesnt work bro it only show the output when i inputed an patientid

Comment: can you display your patient and medicalhistory data sample

Comment: +----+------+--------In Patient Table--------+---------+
| PatientId| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName  |
+----+------+---------------------+---------+
| MMH1    | Dan          | Smith            | chandra |
+----+------+--------------In Medical History-------+---------+                                                                 | PatientId| DoctorId| Evaluation| |
+----+------+---------------------+---------+
| MMH1    | MMHD1   | Sick     |

Comment: what should i do next?

Comment: I have updated the query use that and check if it returns values try out manually

Comment: how would i do that im newbie sorry

Comment: login into mysql database use the database which contains the above data and provide the query select p.id,p.First,p.last, p.middle,pa.id,pa.evalution from test1 as p left join test as pa on (p.id=pa.id) where pa.id='MMH1'; Note change the field names accordingly

Comment: its working however when i only inputing the patient id i just want to input the FirstName Middle Name Last Name in textbox example Peter Parker Smith and it will output the info

Comment: First name, last name and middle name are available in DB rt

Comment: what do you mean available in db rt?

Comment: is the patient table contain all his info? first name, last name and middle why you need to input them again?

Comment: its a search function im in medicalhistory table which is only the patientid is present

Comment: this is my query original query  $query2= mysqli_query($link,"Select
   DISTINCT PatientId from medicalhistory
   where DoctorId='". $dids ."' and PatientId='". $pid ."'" );

Comment: add where pa.DoctorId='". $dids ."' and pa.PatientId='". $pid . and p.Firstname=$first' etc"'" hope you are getting them from $_SESSION

Comment: but its medicalhistory table it will not query

Comment: Check my previous comment you need say pa.doctorid = ? and pa.patientid=? and p.firstname=? and p.lastname=? and p.middlename=?

Comment: select * from patient where CONCAT(PatientId,' ', FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) like '%$pid%'" its like this but iwan to do it in medical history table someone told me to inerjoin im newbie bro im very sorry

Comment: No problem brother see patient table contains id and names rt, medical history contains doctor id, patientid etc.. what you need is list all the data from patient where medical histiory patient id and patientid matches and also names of the patient table

Comment: yes  and the data will depend on doctor who currently in session

Comment: thankyou bro for your time imma countinue this tommorow